# How to write junit for r2dbc for postgres database?

Tags: junit, spring-webflux, junit5, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I have a class which uses used `R2dbcEntityTemplate` as shown below

```
r2dbcTemplate
        .getDatabaseClient()
        .sql("<Custom-Query>")
        .fetch()
        .all();
```

I am connecting to a postgres database, properties of which i am supplying through application.properties.

How do i write JUNIT for this class ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, combining `@DataR2dbcTest` and testcontainers is easy to write db related tests against a real database running in Docker container.

The example test using `@DataR2dbcTest` and testcontainers from my github:

https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryTest.java

For none Spring Boot, it is also easy to prepare a test purposed config, and run on testcontainers via `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Check my example: https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/r2dbc/src/test/java/com/example/demo/domain/PostRepositoryTest.java